# Need ideas to create a Judging algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a PHP rating system (1-5), in which, some judges come rate some products. I want the results of these products to be fair. Normally what happens is some judges are very strict and may rate products only in the range of 1-2. While some judges rate products only in range of 4-5. Some judge correctly between 1-5.

Can some one give an idea or help in creating an algorithm for mean judges which scales the judges' ratings and compute the product score.

I thought of taking mean of the judges scores on all products but is that the way to go forward or some one has another good alternative to get fair results.

**Edit**

The rating system is not for an ecommerce application. Here there are only few judges say 10 who rate all the products. The product may be a song in a contest for example. Some of the judges may be very strict and some very liberal. There maybe several contests, so I have to record ratings of these very strict and liberal judges even for other contests and set a rule for them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to apply an algorithmic solution to a non-algorithmic problem. I'd think about why some "judges" vote only 1-2 and others vote only 4-5.

One possible cause could be self-selection. For example, people who bought an item online may be more likely to review the item if they were particularly disappointed or particularly pleased with their purchase. If this is your problem, you could try to to encourage shoppers to vote more, so that even those who had a non-extreme experience come back to vote.

Another possible issue may be guidance. Maybe your explanation of the rating system isn't clear to the judges. You can try to add a description of what each rating means, and see if that improves the quality of data.

In summary, any kind of a solution to your rating problem will need to have a "human" component and take into account the full story of how the judges choose ratings and why. There is not a whole lot that a ranking algorithm can do if your input data is poor quality. On the other hand, if your data has decent quality, then taking a mean works quite well.

One unrelated problem with taking a mean is that an item with one 5-star rating will rank above an item with hundred 5-star ratings + one 4-star rating. One simple solution is Laplace Smoothing, which addresses the problem by effectively starting every item with one vote of each value (1,2,3,4,5). You don't display the "smoothed" values, but you use them when sorting. See [How Not To Sort By Average Rating](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) post for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about [truncated mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean)? [Here](http://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/201/descstat/mean.htm) is a good explanation of the idea.

**EDIT**

Let's say you have votes like: `[1,4,3,2,5,1,1,3,2,4]`.

You need to sort the array in ascending order, giving you: `[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5]`.

Then let's say you want to get rid of 25% of the votes, which is `3` (rounding up). You simply discard three votes from the left and from the right, giving you `[2,2,3,3]`.

Then, use arithmetic mean to get `2.5`.

**EDIT 2**

Depending on your database schema, you could query the database to return the votes in ascending order. Then, calculate the percentage, use `array_slice()` to help you (read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)) and calculating the arithmetic mean is the least of your concerns now.

Comment: I think this might not work as some judges rate only 1 and 2, while some 4 and 5 and some from 1-5

Comment: Truncated mean is used to eliminate the extremums, so the percentage of truncated values is the key here. You would need to experiment a bit and see if this solution is suitable for your script. Truncated mean ***will not*** disregard all your "1-2 judges" and all your "4-5 judges".

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you assign a weight to a judge based on the range of their typical votes (note, they must not be aware of this weight, or they will throw the system off.) Judges who always vote a single score get the lowest weight. Judges that give things a wide range of scores are considered more accurate.

This also assumes that these judges judge products with a fair range of quality; so if you give them a bunch of good or bad products and expect a range of vote levels, it might be unrealistic.

What you're looking for is the judge with the highest standard deviation (highest variation) in votes having the highest weight, whereas the judge with the lowest would have the least.

The non-algorithmic solution is (essentially) to run the algorithm on the judges, and then pick, American Idol style, judges that balance each other off to get what feels like an accurate result. In which case, you'd want to note the average vote as well as the standard deviation, and perhaps set three judges, one with the wide standard deviation, and then two narrows, one high and one low (liberal and strict) to judge it. This way they don't feel like they get 'less voice' because they are stricter or looser.

Then again, that could be an impetus for them to be less/more strict - if they are too easy or too hard on the product consistently they 'lose voice'.

Comment: Yes you are right it is a judging system. Probably your solution might work but on what condition can one adjust weights. What do you say about using normal distribution.

Comment: w is simply based on standard deviation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation "To calculate the population standard deviation, first compute the difference of each data point from the mean, and square the result of each, Next compute the average of these values, and take the square root of that. " The higher the value that results, the broader scope of results that judge produces.